# Can a program run through Remote Desktop call a program on the client computer?

Tags: client-server, call, remote-desktop

I am developing a program that will be run through Windows remote desktop, and at a certain point it opens a webpage. Someone pointed out that it would be great if the program could launch the webpage on the local PC, though, instead of on the remote PC you're connecting to. This way it would launch in your favorite web browser, would load faster, and you could browse with less latency.

However, is it even possible to do this? Is there some feature of remote desktop that would let me send a command to the user's PC from the session they're logged in to?

If not, is there any other way to do this? For example, I know the clipboard is shared/transferred between client and remote PC when using remote desktop; is there anything I can do to use that?

Thanks in advance for any answers!

Comment: Is there a reason why you're using Remote Desktop? If it's a compatibility thing, there are programs to package a program and run it on any computer (VMWare ThinApp for example), which behaves like a normal application...

Comment: @tjameson the app needs to run on the remote PC because the remote PC is in the same datacenter as some databases and very large files it needs to access.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, this is possible using [Remote Desktop Virtual Channels](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa383509%28v=vs.85%29.aspx). See [here](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/system/TSAddinInCS.aspx) for a C# sample. Since virtual channels have both a client and server piece, this would of course require that all RD clients that want to use the virtual channel have the client bits installed.

Answer (score 2):

The right way is using Virtual Channel as specified by Dan Ports. You need to develop 2 small programs, one on the server and one on the client machine. From the server just send a command to the client through the Virtual Channel, on the client side when receiving the command just run the webpage with the default browser.

There are already free and commercial programs that do that stuff like Remote Executer for Terminal Server, 2X Software product, etc.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post - you can always comment on your own posts, and once you have sufficient [reputation](http://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](http://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment).

Comment: @DamienJoe I think it does provide an answer. It is a bit redundant with the answer I accepted, but it does provide additional info like example software to help accomplish this.